# Create First App for Windows Phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am new Windows Phone App development for A start i want you guys help .Some best tutorials to read and start and please help me how to do complete setup for this development.Please hep me .what i need to start the development process . In which languages can we start the development of Windows Phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, WELCOME to the best mobile platform to develop for. It may not be apparent to you now but the Windows Phone has the best tools and one of the easiest languages to learn supporting it.

As a new Windows Phone Developer you will need a few things to get started:
First you will need to download if you haven't already, Visual Studio Express (or other version if you have it).

[It can be found here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#downloads)

I would recommend downloading **Visual Studio 2012 Express For Windows Phone**

This should also provide you with the SDK

Once this is all installed you are ready to get developing. There is a slew of great tutorials out there on the basics of Windows Phone Development.

When you feel comfortable investing some money into your education I would HIGHLY recommend  [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training) This is a professional learning resource that provides THE BEST video training on the market.

If you want to take a cheaper approach to education then here are a few books I would recommend. [101 Windows Phone Apps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672335522)  and also [Windows Phone 8 A Problem Solution Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430259027) . Though not required, these books will provide you with the solid foundation you need to become a successful developer.

Finally, once you have your app complete you are going to need to get it on the market! Simply sign up for a developer account at the [Windows Phone Developer Hub](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us) They will have all the instructions you need there to getting your app certified and on the market.

Congratulations again on starting in Windows Phone Development. Also welcome to Stack Overflow.

### EDIT# You can find a complete tutorial on my blog [AnthonyRussell.info](http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=45)

Comment: which languages is used for windows phone development and do u have any pdf of tutorials.i am not getting any thing online

Comment: please mail me @ rahul.ranjan2588@gmail.com .i don't have any account at twitter right now.please mail be will be thankful to you always

Comment: @AMR send me the copies at gauravthethinker@gmail.com

Comment: @GauravPandey You're the last one lol. Anyone else interested in contacting me about this can do so on twitter at Anth0nyRussell

Answer (score 0):

[Windowsphone developer page](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us):
I think you will find everything you asked there - and many many more information.

And you should begin with this:
[Getting started guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why not start by the beggining?

Go to the official Windows Phone WebSite and learn the started Tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

After you knows bases, you can read [this](http://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Windows_Phone/), on the Nokia Website for developer... (with lot of tutorial...)